# Equation keeps returning int in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

With the `select` query below:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, cd.LastTestDate, cd.date) / 365.0 AS DateDifference, CAST(1.0 - (cd.DeclRate * ((DATEDIFF(day, cd.LastTestDate, cd.date))/365.0))AS FLOAT) AS DeclRate 
FROM V_INT_PROD_PLAN2 cd
```

I get the following result:

```
DateDifference    DeclRate
0.000000           1
0.002739           1
0.005479           1
```

How can I get the second column to return as a decimal? Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: What datatype is cd.DeclRate?

Comment: Just part of a factor I'm calculating

Comment: Not that it will likely help with the flaot issue but.. can you datediff(year, x, y) instead? Years arent always 365 days long you see

Comment: try something like SELECT ROUND(CAST((DATEDIFF(day, cd.LastTestDate, cd.date)) AS float) /365.0 , 2)

Comment: @Danieleo i think the problem he faces is not that the column lacks decimal point, but that a loss of precision is going on because the maths reverts to integer mode at some point

Comment: Multiply or divide the final result wit 1.0

Comment: @CaiusJard fair point re years not being 365 days long. cd.DeclRate is  numeric(20,8)

Comment: can you post some example values of cd.LastTestDate, cd.date and cd.DeclRate

Comment: ps, maybe ignore the datediff(year) i mentioned 'cause datediff returns ints and that really will lose precision!

Comment: please run this query and post the results: `SELECT cd.LastTestDate, cd.date, cd.DeclRate, DATEDIFF(day, cd.LastTestDate, cd.date) / 365.0 AS DateDifference, CAST(1.0 - (cd.DeclRate * ((DATEDIFF(day, cd.LastTestDate, cd.date))/365.0))AS FLOAT) AS DeclRate 
FROM V_INT_PROD_PLAN2 cd`

Comment: incidentally, i looked deeper into datediff as a result of this q and found something that really appalled me.. Asking datediff for the number of days between two dates 1 minute apart will either return 0 or 1 depending on whether the 1 minute timespan crosses midnight or not.. What a disaster!

Comment: Check if   `cd.DeclRate` is `0`, or date difference is `0`

Comment: @Pரதீப் Agreed with you on that, of course. Then casting to `decimal` data type needs to be performed, to correctly handle the precision,  not to `float` data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the values in the second column is giving you a value that is resulting in an `int`, which in turn is converting the output to an `int`. See the below samples:

```
DECLARE @DeclRate AS NUMERIC(20, 8);
DECLARE @FromDate AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @ToDate AS DATETIME;

SET @DeclRate = 0.000000123;
SET @FromDate = GETDATE();
SET @ToDate = GETDATE() + 1;

-- not int result
SELECT CAST(1.0 - (@DeclRate * ((DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate)) 
            / 365.0)) AS FLOAT) AS DeclRate;

-- set variable to 0 value
SET @DeclRate = 0.0000;
-- output is int result
SELECT CAST(1.0 - (@DeclRate * ((DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate)) 
            / 365.0)) AS FLOAT) AS DeclRate;

-- set dates to be same day
SET @ToDate = GETDATE();
SET @DeclRate = 0.000000123;
-- output is int result
SELECT CAST(1.0 - (@DeclRate * ((DATEDIFF(DAY, @FromDate, @ToDate)) 
            / 365.0)) AS FLOAT) AS DeclRate;
```

My suspicion is that the date comparison you are doing is comparing dates that are the same, therefore `@DeclRate * (datediff...` will always result in `0` being output.

Comment: "My suspicion is that the date comparison you are doing is comparing dates that are the same" - but how do we ratify this against the posted example data that shows `SELECT DATEDIFF(day, cd.LastTestDate, cd.date) / 365.0 AS DateDifference, ...` is returning floats (first column of example result data).. Surely the dates must be different..

Comment: ps; did you intend for your TO date to be before (-1) your FROM date? `SET @ToDate = GETDATE() - 1;`

Comment: @CaiusJard i did intend it to be `+1` but the result is the same either way. the last section in my code changes the dates to match so it can be ratified. The OP didn't post sample data, so at best this is a guess at the issue.

Comment: Always puzzles me why these OPs vanish without trace when the question activity starts going in their favour, people responding, engaging etc..